# Lookup populated columns and get smallest number of another col

Tags: indexing, filter, lambda, match, vlookup

I am fairly experienced Excel formula user of filters and VLOOKUP's, but not sure how to combine the two things together in a formula.

[what is the lowest age of a specified fruit?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRgNM.png)

Can I make a formula to lookup the lowest age of any specified column - Lowest age of apples is 12, lowest age of oranges is 14, lowest age of bananas is 12.

I've been looking at some posts that use Index/Match, MMATCH, LAMBDA. I have no experience of MMATCH and LAMBDA but seems like those functions may help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you place your picture of the sample data beginning in A1, then the columns showing fruits are columns B-D and the ages are in column E.

Then:

```
=MIN(  FILTER(E2:E9,  INDEX(B2:D9,,MATCH(F13,B1:D1,0))  <>0))
```

will work.

`INDEX` works over the data's range, B2:D9, and that can be expanded as needed. It uses `MATCH` on the header row, B1:D1 in this case, to find the column number to return and the `,,` in the middle makes it return all the rows in said column.

That column becomes the value to be tested by `FILTER`. `INDEX` used this way will return 0 instead of blanks. If that somehow creates a problem, make this portion a bit more complicated by wrapping it in an `IF` test returning `""` if empty, and whatever, if not.

`FILTER` then returns the matching row values in the age column.

That list is fed to `MIN` to find the youngest age.

Comment: AWESOME!!!  This answers my question.  Thank you Jeorje for the detailed explanation.  That really helps me understand how it works!!!!